# Invalid literal for int() with base 10 in my views after it worked a while

Tags: python, django, integer, message, literals

I'm keep getting this error Invalid literal for int() with base 10
from the views in my django project after it worked for a while ,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/srv/cc/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner

    response = get_response(request)
  File "/srv/cc/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response

    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/srv/cc/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view

    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "./core/views.py", line 133, in send_message
    if int(uid2) == uid:

Exception Type: ValueError at /msg/new
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4,016'
```

Here is My views.py looks like

```
def chat_detail(request, pk):
    chat = Chat.objects.get(pk=pk)
    added, lm = chat.new(request.user)
    if lm:
        lm.msg = chat.current_last_msg
        lm.save()
    recepient = chat.recepient(request.user)
    return render(request, 'core/chat.html', {'chat': chat, 'recepient': recepient})
def chat_with_user(request, uid):
    chat = Chat.get_or_create(request.user.id, int(uid))
    return redirect(f'/chat/{chat.id}')
def chats(request):
    user_chats = []
    for c in Chat.of_user(request.user):
        user_chats.append({'rec': c.recepient(request.user),
                           'unread': len(c.new(request.user)[0]),
                           'chat': c})
    return render(request, 'core/chats.html', {'user_chats': user_chats})
def send_message(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        m = Message()
        uid = request.user.id
        uid2 = request.POST.get('uid2', None)
        if uid2 is None:
            return {}
        if int(uid2) == uid:
            return {}
        m.chat = Chat.get_or_create(uid, int(uid2))
        m.sender = request.user
        m.text = request.POST.get('text')
        m.save()
        return redirect(f'/chat/{m.chat.id}')
    else:
        return {}
```

And here all the  message models.py

```
class LastMessage(models.Model):
    chat = models.ForeignKey('Chat', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    msg = models.ForeignKey(Message, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Chat(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
    @property
    def msgs(self):
        return self.message_set.all()

    def new(self, user):
        lm = self.last_msg_for(user)
        if lm:
            return self.added(lm.msg), lm
        else:
            return [], None

    def added(self, start_msg):
        return self.message_set.filter(id__gt=start_msg.id).all()

    @property
    def current_last_msg(self):
        try:
            return list(self.msgs)[-1]
        except:
            return None

    def last_msg_for(self, user):
        lm = self.current_last_msg
        if lm:
            lm_user = LastMessage.objects.filter(chat=self, user=user).first()
            if lm_user is None:
                lm_user = LastMessage.objects.create(chat=self, user=user, msg=lm)
            return lm_user
        return None

    def recepient(self, cur_user):
        for u in self.users.all():
            if u.id != cur_user.id:
                return u
        return None

    @classmethod
    def get_or_create(cls, uid, uid2):
        chat = cls.objects.filter(users=uid).filter(users=uid2).first()
        if chat is None:
            chat = cls()
            chat.save()
            chat.users.set([uid, uid2])
            chat.save()
        return chat

    @classmethod
    def of_user(cls, user):
        return cls.objects.filter(users=user).all()
```

please help me I'm beginner in django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you should use `int(float(uid2))` if uid2 is a string representing a `float`.
The second problem is that you uid2 represents a float using `,` instead of `.` (I don't know if , is used for decimal points or as a thounsands separator) and you need to add a `replace()`.

```
int(float(uid2.replace(",", "."))) if comma is used for decimal points
int(float(uid2.replace(",", ""))) if comma is used as a thounsands separator
```

Comment: Thanks man it's worked , it's a thounsands separator , it's a user id of message recipient user uid2 .